# In Windows 7, how do I change the picture position differently per desktop wallpaper?

Tags: windows-7, desktop, desktop-customization

I have about 10 desktop wallpapers on a slideshow, some I want to fill up the screen and others I want centered.  If I select `Fill` for `Picture Position` then all the desktop wallpapers are set to fill...  Even the ones I want centered!

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to really separate them, I would suggest to create a canvas the size of your screen and place the pictures were you want them, then place those images (canvas/pictures) into the folder you want to rotate around, this would allow you to see those images centered if you make the canvas black and place the image in the middle.

Comment: +1 While this does have the drawback that, should you decide to change your setting for desktop background color, you'd have to edit every image you do this to, it's still probably the only way to accomplish this objective. (Afterthought: could you make the "canvassed" image a PNG with a transparent padding area?)